# ECS service discovery and port mapping on fargate

Tags: amazon-ecs, service-discovery, ecs-service-connect

I have a few hundred microservices that I'm migrating into ECS.

Developers need to call endpoints in them from locally, so I have used service discovery with a private dns zone which resolves over VPN, every app can now be accessed from a friendly url in the format `[appname].ecs.private:[port]`

This is working fine but the issue is they all run on different ports and so the developer needs to go find what particular port the app is running on.

I wanted to be able to simply call `[appname].ecs.private` and it be mapped through, I thought I'd be able to use port mapping to map port 80 to the container port on each app. However it gives an error that `hostPort` and `containerPort` must match in awsvpc mode.

Am I missing something or is what I wanted to do just not possible?